# jHipster: how to generate only entities during jdl import

Tags: java, jhipster, code-generation, jdl

jHipster: how to generate only entities during jdl import

or entities plus dto and mappers?

```
jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh
```

Comment: Helo, I notice that qualificator --skip-server dont work with latest version of jhipster. I try this framework and analyze his potentiality, but I have problems to separate frontend code by backend for this anomaly. Actually I have same issues, and read you I think that the solution is open a ticket jiira about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generate just entities (and skip application JDL generation), you can pass `--ignore-application`. The full command will look like: `jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh --ignore-application`

If you want DTOs and Mappers, add `dto * with mapstruct` to the bottom of your JDL. 
 More info in the docs: https://jhipster.tech/jdl/

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `--ignore-application` flag, it's wonderful! Without that the import was re-generating all classes, but using it only the new ones or modified are created! Wow thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jhipster entity <entityName> --[options]` where options are:

- `--skip-server` - This will skip the server-side code and will generate only the client-side code.
- `--skip-client` - This will skip the client-side code and will generate only the server-side code.

Check: https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/